Colored Output for Elisp Script
I am trying to get a "shell script" based on Elisp to output colors.  However, so far I was not successful.  I found this answer and simply tried it verbatim, but the output was standard with the ANSI sequences removed.  The message area shows a hash-led list with the text as first object and the properties following when dumping it there.
While when using (insert) with (ansi-color-apply), the colors are shown in the buffer, it appears that neither (princ)/(print) nor (message) will handle colors when outputting text (to a terminal).  The properties are simply ignored.  Is there a different way to achieve getting colored output as if using bash?

We'd need to see your actual code to be able to tell you what's wrong with it. Please review the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

If you run a shell script in a terminal, try ansi-term instead of whatever you are using now.

The linked answer already contains that code you are asking for.  As mentioned, I copied it verbatim (that is, as is) and it still does not output any colors.  The only addition is the shebang using #!/bin/emacs --x in the first line.

(ansi-term) appears to start a terminal emulator from within Emacs according to the help text.  Since I am already in a terminal when this script starts, this would not be useful.  The script actually runs, just without colors.  So, the functionality is there, but using the default terminal colors.  What I am trying to achieve is to get specific colors for some section of the text output into said terminal.

I'm afraid that's probably not going to be easy. As a crude workaround, can you intercept the interaction and run the command in an ansi-term buffer, then copy the results back into the current buffer?

I tried that as well.  I actually tried both, creating a separate buffer and (with-temp-buffer), copied it out (buffer-string) (not (buffer-string-no-properties)!).  If the pasted text is landing in another buffer it works, but as soon as it is "pasted" (through either princ or message) into the terminal, all properties appear to get removed.

"If the pasted text is landing in another buffer it works" Because you are copying text properties with buffer-string from ansi-term where conversion from ANSI codes to Emacs properties has been done for you. Princ and message are creating new strings without any text properties, so where should colors come from? You have to propertize the string with your color. Look at propertize function and related chapters about text properties, faces, font-lock, etc in Emacs Lisp manual. Also take a look into source code for ansi-term to see how they convert ANSI colors to something Emacs can render.

@myname, unfortunately that does not add anything beyond the already discovered and/or discussed.

"that does not add anything beyond the already discovered" How come? You seem not aware of the fact that princ/print/prin1 & co generate new strings since they convert object representation to a string. Message also generates a new string with the help of the format string you enter. I don't see it pointed out. I don't see anyone telling you to use propertize to add text properties to your strings, nor that ANSI codes need to be converted into Emacs colors. From your last message, you had no idea why copying buffer-string "works" but princ does not. Start reading the manual!
